# How to remove WooCommerce customer-details from order received page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce would like to remove the billing address from the thankyou page. (see picture). How exactly do I do that? What code do I need to add to the functions.php file

[image]

I would like to remove the billing address from the order received page.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing. I find nothing useful on the Internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide (or remove) customer details from order received page, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'hide_order_recieved_customer_details', 10 , 1 );
function hide_order_recieved_customer_details( $template_name ) {
    // Targeting thankyou page and the customer details
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) && strpos($template_name, 'order-details-customer.php') !== false ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $template_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.
Tested and works.

> **Alternatively**, you can also [override](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) and customize `order/order-details-customer.php` template file, using `is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' )` conditional tag, to target specifically the Thankyou page.